# Sort related table data

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am having troubles to sorting the result data of table in a view of my cakephp system. I can show all the result data of table, but I can't get to sorting that.

I was able to create the Paginator link to sort by order direction asc and desc, but when a click it, the order stays the same, although the url link and the arrow figure change the direction, asc and desc.

In my system I have three tables related as follow:

- Disc hasMany Audio
- Audio belongsTo Disc, Audio hasMany Moment
- Moment  belongsTo Audio

My php Models are look like as follow:

Disc.php:

```
class Disc extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Disc';
    public $hasMany = array(
    'Audio' => array(
            'className' => 'Audio',
            'foreignKey' => 'Disc_id',
            'order' => 'Audio.id DESC'
            )
    );
```

Audio.php:

```
class Audio extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Audio';
    public $belongsTo = array(
    'Disc' => array(
            'className' => 'Disc',
            'foreignKey' => 'Disc_id'
            )
    );
    public $hasMany = array(
    'Moment' => array(
            'className' => 'Moment',
            'foreignKey' => 'audio_id'
            )
    );
```

Moment.php:

```
class Moment extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Moment';
    public $belongsTo = array(
    'Audio' => array(
            'className' => 'Audio',
            'foreignKey' => 'audio_id'
            )
    );
```

My php Controllers are look like as follow:

DiscsController:

```
class DiscsController extends AppController {
...
    public function view($id = null) {
        $this->Disc->recursive = 2; # or -1, 0, 1, 2, 3
        $this->Disc->id = $id;
        $this->set('disc', $this->Disc->read());
        //$this->set('audio', $this->paginate());

        $conditions = array("Audio.disc_id" => "$id");
        $this->set('audio', $this->paginate('Audio', $conditions)); 
        // note "plan" in the first argument of set (this is required to pass the results back to the view). Also.
        //The $condition is set to return ONLY plans that match the plan_detail_id of id (on the plan_details table).

    }
...
```

AudiosController:

```
class AudiosController extends AppController {
...
    public function view($id = null) {
        $this->Audio->id = $id;
        $this->set('audio', $this->Audio->read());
        $this->set('audios', $this->paginate());
    }
...
```

And my Discs/view.ctp is look like as follow:

```
<table>
    <!-- Sort -->
    <tr>
        <th><?php  echo $this->Paginator->sort('id', 'DID'); ?></th>
        <th><?php  echo $this->Paginator->sort('audio.id', 'AID'); ?></th>
        <th><?php  echo $this->Paginator->sort('Audio.name', 'Audio Name'); ?></th>
        <th><?php  echo $this->Paginator->sort('moment.played','Audio Played') ;?></th>
    </tr>

<!-- foreach ($disc['Audio'] as $audio): -->
<?php foreach ($disc['Audio'] as $audio): ?>
    <?php foreach ($audio['Moment'] as $moment): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $audio['Disc']['id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $audio['id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $audio['name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $moment['played']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The url params when I click to sort are:

DID:

```
http://localhost/cakephp/discs/view/3/sort:id/direction:asc
```

AID:

```
http://localhost/cakephp/discs/view/3/sort:audio.id/direction:asc
```

Audio Name:

```
http://localhost/cakephp/discs/view/3/sort:Audio.name/direction:asc
```

Audio Played:

```
http://localhost/cakephp/discs/view/3/sort:moment.played/direction:asc
```

Maybe it is something simple, I am new at cakephp, but I searched a lot for a solution, but no successful.

Please, help me.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT 2:

Thank you Anubhav, I was out for some days, but now I'm back.

Sorry but I didn't understand very well what you asked. Please check if was it you asked.

I've set  Configure::write('debug', 3) in app/config/core.php.

So, I tried to use print_r array('order' => "$sortBy.$order"), but I faced this error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ARRAY.

Then, I used Debugger::dump(array('order' => "$sortBy.$order")); and when I accessed `http://localhost/cakephp/discs/view/3/sort:id/direction:asc` it returned this:

```
array(
    'order' => 'Audio.id.DESC'
)
```

When I access `http://localhost/cakephp/discs/view/3/sort:id/direction:asc`

I don't face any database error, but the paginator still doesn't run.

But when I access just the `http://localhost/cakephp/discs/view/3`

I get that Database Erro I said before:
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Audio.id.DESC' in 'order clause'

And the SQL Query is:

```
SQL Query: SELECT `Audio`.`id`, `Audio`.`disc_id`, `Audio`.`name`, `Audio`.`downloaded`, `Audio`.`inserted`, `Disc`.`id`, `Disc`.`title`, `Disc`.`site`, `Disc`.`stream`, `Disc`.`type`, `Disc`.`command`, `Disc`.`comment`, `Disc`.`created`, `Disc`.`modified` FROM `disc_server`.`audios` AS `Audio` LEFT JOIN `disc_server`.`discs` AS `Disc` ON (`Audio`.`disc_id` = `Disc`.`id`) WHERE `Audio`.`disc_id` = 3 ORDER BY `Audio`.`id`.DESC ASC LIMIT 20
```

Sorry If I forget something, thank you so much again for the help.

EDIT 3:

Thank You Anubhav.

I changed the

```
 $this->paginate = array('order' => "$sortBy.$order");
```

to

```
 $this->paginate = array('order' => "$sortBy $order");
```

And the database error disappeared.

The result of Debugger::dump(array('order' => "$sortBy $order")) is:

```
array(
    'order' => 'Audio.id ASC'
)
```

Now I can access `http://localhost/cakephp/discs/view/3/` with no problem, but I still can't get to sorting.

I realized that following SQL query (Nr 2):

```
SELECT `Audio`.`id`, `Audio`.`disc_id`, `Audio`.`name`, `Audio`.`downloaded`, `Audio`.`inserted`, `Audio`.`Disc_id` FROM `disc_server`.`audios` AS `Audio` WHERE `Audio`.`Disc_id` = (3) ORDER BY `Audio`.`id` DESC
```

only change its order (DESC or ASC), if I change the order in Disc.php Model:

```
'order' => 'Audio.id DESC'
```

or

```
'order' => 'Audio.id ASC'
```

if I do that, the data result list is sorted as ordered in Disc.php Model.

But, if I trying to sort by access the sort indicator links:

```
http://localhost/cakephp/discs/view/3/sort:audio.id/direction:desc
```

and

```
http://localhost/cakephp/discs/view/3/sort:audio.id/direction:asc
```

it does not affect the SQL query order. Even if I change order in the function view:

```
public function view($id = null,$sortBy='Audio.id',$order='DESC')
```

or

```
public function view($id = null,$sortBy='Audio.id',$order='ASC')
```

That query order still the same.

I think paginate in the function view is not get to sort the data for some reason.
There is something strange when I access only:

```
http://localhost/cakephp/discs/view/3
```

the other query (Nr 7) is:

```
SELECT `Audio`.`id`, `Audio`.`disc_id`, `Audio`.`name`, `Audio`.`downloaded`, `Audio`.`inserted`, `Disc`.`id`, `Disc`.`title`, `Disc`.`site`, `Disc`.`stream`, `Disc`.`type`, `Disc`.`command`, `Disc`.`comment`, `Disc`.`created`, `Disc`.`modified` FROM `disc_server`.`audios` AS `Audio` LEFT JOIN `disc_server`.`discs` AS `Disc` ON (`Audio`.`disc_id` = `Disc`.`id`) WHERE `Audio`.`disc_id` = 3 ORDER BY `Audio`.`id` DESC LIMIT 20
```

The order of this query (Nr 7) is related only to:

```
public function view($id = null,$sortBy='Audio.id',$order='DESC')
```

So if I change $order='DESC' to ASC the query (Nr 7) changes its order. But it does not change the order of data result list.

When I sort by accessing the sort indicator links:

```
http://localhost/cakephp/discs/view/3/sort:audio.id/direction:desc
```

or

```
http://localhost/cakephp/discs/view/3/sort:audio.id/direction:asc
```

the query (Nr 7) doesn't have order indicator. It becomes this way:

```
SELECT `Audio`.`id`, `Audio`.`disc_id`, `Audio`.`name`, `Audio`.`downloaded`, `Audio`.`inserted`, `Disc`.`id`, `Disc`.`title`, `Disc`.`site`, `Disc`.`stream`, `Disc`.`type`, `Disc`.`command`, `Disc`.`comment`, `Disc`.`created`, `Disc`.`modified` FROM `disc_server`.`audios` AS `Audio` LEFT JOIN `disc_server`.`discs` AS `Disc` ON (`Audio`.`disc_id` = `Disc`.`id`) WHERE `Audio`.`disc_id` = 3 LIMIT 20
```

Sorry, It's all so confused, but I hope these informations help us to find a solution for this trouble.

Thank you so much for help me.

Comment: add url params at the time of sorting in your question

Comment: Anubhav, I've did, do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Change your view function as shown below:
You have to change sorting criteria in your view function:

```
public function view($id = null,$sortBy='Audio.id',$order='DESC') {
        $this->Disc->recursive = 2; # or -1, 0, 1, 2, 3
        $this->Disc->id = $id;
        $this->set('disc', $this->Disc->read());
        # set sorting criteria for paginator            
        $this->paginate = array('order' => "$sortBy $order");

        $conditions = array("Audio.disc_id" => "$id");
        $this->set('audio', $this->paginate('Audio', $conditions)); 


    }
```

Comment: Thank you Anubhav, I did as you said, but I didn't get successful, please take a look my updated question.

Comment: @user2155042 see this url has three parameters page number, field name and order http://localhost/cakephp/discs/view/3/sort:id/direction:asc, so first print_r array('order' => "$sortBy.$order"), it will give you little insight about the query. Now after that set debug level 3 and see the final output query , and pls share that query.

Comment: @user2155042 see updated answer, array('order' => "$sortBy $order");